# Ssh via zerotier while cloudflare WARP is active does not work

Tags: networking, ssh, cloudflare

So I am using WARP on desktop....but whenever I enable that, my ssh server in that pc cannot be connected to anymore...neither can I ping it...any help would be appreciated thanks.

I am using zerotier to ping / ssh my pc.

Comment: Using two "vpn"s at the same time commonly doesn't work. 
You can try restarting zerotier after enabling warp, or waiting 5 minutes to see if it reconnects.